# How to retrive facebook page likes count in graph API? API returning empty set

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, php-curl

When i try to get facebook pages likes count using graph api, I dint get anything likes page likes count.

`GET /v2.10/{page_id}/likes RETURNS empty set`

So i try

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{PAGE_ID}?fields=id,name,likes.summary(true),link&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}`

```
RESULT : 
{
   "id": "513727248979119",
   "name": "Trending men's wear",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Trending-mens-wear-513727248979119/"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the number of users who like the Page. use `fan_count` instead of `likes`. As per the documentation description of `likes` and `fan_count` are same. but `fan_count` is working fine. 
So use

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{PAGE_ID}?fields=id,name,**fan_count**,link&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}`

ref:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/